# Scroolbars showing when they should not with IE 7, why?

Tags: css, positioning

I've style an div that will contain content that might vary in height and width in following way:

```
div.myDiv {
   display:inline-block;
   *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
   *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
   white-space:normal;
   vertical-align:top; max-width:280px; overflow:auto; 
}
```

Intention is to limit expansion of element beyond 280 pixels and let the content grow vertically since I have a overflow: auto on container element. This works fine for all the browsers except IE7. I'm not sure if offset have anything to do with this problem?

[image]

Edit: [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/krul/pBdaX/) where I've setup jsfiddle to demonstrate my scenario but I can't even view jsfiddle with IE9 (run in IE 7 mode). Hopefully this will help in understanding the problem I'm facing.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you develop for IE7? It has far below 1% usage. It's a huge waste of time imo.

Comment: unfortunately I have no freedom to drop support as I'm working for company that has contractual obligations to support ie7 (I hope not for long)

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't work in Browser mode of IE7. At least not for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `overflow:hidden`:

```
div.myDiv {
   display:inline-block;
   *display:inline;/* For IE7*/
   *zoom:1;/* For IE7*/
   white-space:normal;
   vertical-align:top; max-width:280px; overflow:auto; 

   /*This line should hide the scrollbar*/

   *overflow:hidden;
}
```